# Why does the following javascript cause Unresponsive Script error?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop

When trying out the code below as a solution for the Euler Project problem 5. The problem is find the smallest number equally divisible by all numbers from 1 to 20. Every time it is run it presents "Unresponsive Script" window and I need to physically stop the script from running. It seems like something is causing it to hang but I can't quite figure out what. The alert window seems to point to an error with the line the while() starts on but I can't see anything wrong with it.If it looks like it should work I'd appreciate anyone trying it on their machine to see if it works. That way I can eliminate it as a local problem. All suggestions welcome.

```
var divisible = false;
var n = 2520; // first number divisible by all numbers 1-10

while(divisible === false){ // something wrong here??
    n += 2520;
    for(var i = 11; i < n; i++) {

        if(i % n !== 0){ 
            break; 
        }
        if(i === 20) {
            divisible === true;
        }
    }
}
if(divisible === true){
    return console.log("Answer: " +i);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you break out of your `for` loop if `i % n` isn't 0 the very first time. And you never set `divisible` to `true` - `divisible === true` isn't the same as `divisible = true`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out those glaring errors. I of course spotted a few others, such as `n` instead of `20` in the loop condition.Can't believe I missed that! However, the `break` is intentional to cancel the loop when the first non divisible number is found for each new value of `n`. If `i` reaches the value of 20 we know all the numbers were divided equally into whatever the value of `n` is on that iteration and so can set `divisible` to true and return `n`. I believe it works as intended now so I'll post the working code in an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in the original code, some pointed out in the answer above. To make it work several fixes are needed.
First, the boolean `divisible` must be correctly set to `true` using the assignment operator `=` inside the `for loop` instead of `===` which is used only to check if two values are strictly of the same type AND value.
The next problem is the conditional part of the for loop `i < n` should be `i < 20` because the loop is checking if numbers between 11 and 20 divide evenly into `n`.The last fix to make the code run correctly is the order of the condition if the first `if` statement which should read `if(n % i !== 0)` and not `if(i % n !== 0)`. I think it might be this specific part that caused the code to crash and generate the "Unresponsive Script" alert in the browser.
Here is the fixed code.

```
var divisible = false;
var n = 2520; // smallest number divisible by all numbers 1-10

while(divisible === false){
    n += 2520; // increment n on each new pass
    // loop numbers between 11 and 20 
    for(var i = 11; i <= 20; i++) {

        if(n % i !== 0){ // check if i divides equally into n
        // if not break out of current loop and start again 
            break; 
        }
        // if i reaches 20 then all the numbers divided equally into n
        if(i === 20) {
        // set value of divisible to true to cancel while loop
            divisible = true;
        }
    }
}
// return the last value of n
return console.log("Answer: " +n);
```